# Multiple before functions in HSpec?

Tags: haskell, scotty, hspec

I have an in-memory repository that I can create by calling this function:

```
newEmptyRepository :: IO InMemoryGameRepository
```

where `InMemoryGameRepository` is defined like this:

```
type State = (HashMap GameId Game)
type IORefState = IORef State
newtype InMemoryGameRepository = InMemoryGameRepository IORefState
```

When writing tests for my Scotty application I've seen examples of using this approach:

```
spec =
  before app $ do
    describe "GET /" $ do
      it "responds with 200" $ get "/" `shouldRespondWith` 200
      it "responds with 'hello'" $ get "/" `shouldRespondWith` "hello"
    ...
```

This is all fine but I need to somehow also initialize the InMemoryGameRepository (by calling `newEmptyRepository`) and use the created instance in my tests. Thus I've changed `app` to:

```
app :: InMemoryGameRepository -> IO Application
app repo = scottyApp $ routes repo
```

And I'm trying to create a test that uses the repository AND the `IO Application`, for example like this (which doesn't work):

```
spec = 
    before (do repo <- newEmptyRepository
               app repo) $ 
      -- API Tests
      describe "GET /api/games" $ 
        it "responds with " $ do
          liftIO $ startGame repo
          get "/api/games" `shouldRespondWith` singleGameResponse
```

where `startGame` is defined like this:

```
startGame :: InMemoryGameRepository -> IO Game
```

Here the compiler says (obviously) that `repo` is not in scope. But how can I achieve this? I.e. I want to share a single instance of `newEmptyRepository` both for the `app` and in the test?

Ps: you can see the full application on [github](https://github.com/johanhaleby/rps-haskell).

Comment: [`beforeWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hspec-2.4.4/docs/Test-Hspec.html#v:beforeWith)? e.g. `before newEmptyRepository . beforeWith app`

Comment: I still don't understand how I can get a hold of the `newEmptyRepository` instance from this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. With that code, the result of `newEmptyRepository` is passed to `app` - that is now you access it (by manipulating the argument to `app`). Or maybe you mean you want to access both the `InMemoryGameRepository` and the `Application` in your test definitions - then just use `app' r = (,) r <$> app r`. Aside: you shouldn't use `liftIO $ startGame repo` in the test definition; use `before_` for this (or just call `startGame` in `app`).

Comment: Maybe you could add it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [beforeWith](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hspec-2.4.4/docs/Test-Hspec.html#v:beforeWith) which has the type

```
beforeWith :: (b -> IO a) -> SpecWith a -> SpecWith b
```

Use it as e.g. `before newEmptyRepository . beforeWith app` whose type is `SpecWith Application -> Spec`.

If you want to access both the `InMemoryGameRepository` and the `Application` in your test cases, defined a helper function

```
withArg f a = (,) a <$> f a
withArg :: Functor f => (t -> f b) -> t -> f (t, b)
```

then use

```
before newEmptyRepository . beforeWith (withArg app)
    :: SpecWith (InMemoryGameRepository, Application) -> Spec
```

Finally, you shouldn't use `liftIO $ startGame repo` in the definition of your tests - this runs `startGame` every time the test tree is built (although, this may actually be what you want, it doesn't seem to be the case). Instead, if you use the `before` family of functions, `startGame` will run once before the tests are actually run. You can even access the `Game` returned by `startGame` using the same technique as above:

```
  before newEmptyRepository 
. beforeWith (withArg startGame) 
. beforeWith (withArg $ app . fst)
:: SpecWith ((InMemoryGameRepository, Game), Application) -> Spec
```